# geometry question on rhombus

Tags: geometry

ABCD is a convex quadrilaterals with P,Q,R,S, midpoints of sides AB,BC,CD and DA respectively. Such that triangles AQR and triangles CSP are equilateral.How do I prove that ABCD is a rhombus and calculate its angles measures?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Since $PS\parallel QR$ (both are parallel to $BD$), $\angle AHS=60^\circ$. Therefore, $\triangle AHI$ is equilateral and $AQ\parallel CS$. Similarly, we can show that the six small triangles are all equilateral.

Moreover, since $SR\parallel AC$ and $SR=\dfrac{AC}2$, it follows that $SJ:JC=JR:AJ=1:2$. So the six small triangles are of ratio $1:3$ to **both** $\triangle AQR$ and $\triangle CPS$.

It then follows that $S$ lies on the circle with diameter $JA$, so $\angle ASC=90^\circ$, and that $\angle JAS=30^\circ$. Similarly $\angle ARS=30^\circ$, and so $\angle CAR=30^\circ$ (because $AC\parallel SR$). Thus $\angle CAD=60^\circ$.

A similar argument gives us that $\angle ACD=60^\circ$. So $\triangle ACD$ is equilateral.

Again, by a similar argument $\triangle ACB$ is equilateral. Thus, $ABCD$ is a rhombus with angles equal to $120^\circ$ and $60^\circ$.

*Note:* The last statements of the 1st and 2nd paragraphs are left for you to verify.

Comment: SJ:JC=JR:AJ=1:2 please explain and also  S lies on the circle with diameter JA